# Blurry SVG images in chrome for Android

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, svg

---

To escape the hell of different pixel densities in mobile phones, I use SVG-files as background images in my css.

Chrome for android seems to render inline-svg just fine, but fails if the svg

- is used in css with `background-image` and a normal url
- is used in css with `background-image` and a data uri
- is used with an `image` element

The stock browser of android 4 works just fine. (and all other mobile phones I tried, too)

You can visit [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rc8Hh/1/) and check it out. Zoom in to see the difference.

Anyone knows why chrome uses some pre-rendered bitmaps here?

Comment: Hmm weird, only the inline-svg element is sharp.

Comment: good to know, so it's not my eyes :)

Comment: I've got an issue on my Nexus 7 all SVG's look fine except the conference title on the blue background. It blurry to the point it just looks like white haze. http://summit.usu.edu/ It's an img element. What is "inline svg"?

Comment: I'm also having trouble with this bug. Its mentioned here on the chromium issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=161982 It's listed as been fixed, due for roll out when chrome is updated 'early 2013'. I'm testing on a new nexus 4 with android 4.2.2 and chrome 18.0.1025469 and its still broken.

Comment: +1 - having the same issue when using an SVG as a background-image. Oddly enough, if I zoom in and out, sometimes the SVG will render crisply. The rest of the time it looks horrible.

Answer (score 14):

As other answers have pointed out in this issue and other similar issues SVG's rendering is problematic in chrome and the native android web browser.  It's a known chrome / native browser issue.

After looking at many solutions over a number of days I stumbled on this workaround by chance.  The trick is to embed text inside the SVG file, this can be single transparent character.

For Example, add this (or similar) to your SVG files.

```
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 7.1079 13.5215)" opacity="0" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="12">a</text>
```

Without investigating the actual chrome source or processes I can only assume that by embedding text it is forcing the SVG to be re-rendered on scale-up for the high dpi devices.

This solution (on the browsers I've been able to test on Android/Chrome) works no matter how the background-image element is used, rotations, fixed position etc.  And even seems to be clear under zoom.

Enjoy!

Comment: This is exactly the solution! Like a magic.  One other thing, I have snap.svg library on my Ionic app. The animation is not working on the Android as well. The SVG is clear now b/c of your hack. But the animation still not showing...

Answer (score 10):

This is a known issue https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=161982

When SVG was rendered as a image (or background image) it was originally rendered to CSS pixel density, making it blurry on devices where 1 CSS px != 1 device px, which includes most high-end Android phones.

That issue was fixed in Chrome 25 (current version at time of writing), however the images become blurry again as you zoom the viewport in.

This issue is fixed in Chrome 26 (currently Chrome Beta, available in the play store), SVG images and backgrounds remain sharp.

Comment: +1 - "it was originally rendered to CSS pixel density, making it blurry on devices where 1 CSS px != 1 device px". Good explanation; that's exactly the behavior I see, resulting in an image that looks much worse than a raster graphic (PNG, JPEG, BMP, etc.) would.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution whilst it took a very long to discover was my elements css:

```
border-radius: 4px;
```

This fixed my issues, however I have not been able to recreate it over than on the site I have been working on but here is the fiddle that I was trying to recreate the problem on mobile:

http://jsfiddle.net/rc8Hh/31/

Good luck, my advise check if there is a class that might be affecting the drawing of the element.

Answer (score 0):

If you are inserting a SVG file, the file will be (depending on the host, Wikipedia for example) pre-rendered. So therefore on load, the image will render for the size given. Inline SVG (Directly Coded into page) will re-size when the page re-sizes. But, I'm not sure about mobile browsers as they don't resize the elements in the page, they just "zoom"

So basically what you're doing is painting an SVG onto a Canvas (pun!) then zooming a canvas. Inline has the direct SVG... so better....

Answer (score 0):

In my case I found that the culprit was a filter attribtue

```
<g filter="url(#filter0_d)">
```

By removing the filter attribute, the SVG was rendered as a vector rather than as a bitmap.

```
<g>
```

For good measure I removed the `<filter>` tag as well

```
<filter id="filter0_d" x="-261" y="50" width="1490" height="950" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/>
<feOffset/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="12.5"/>
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="shape"/>
</filter>
```