# Blurry SVGs when used as background images or with img tag on Android Chrome/Webkit

Tags: android, svg, image, inline

Chrome Version: 25.0.1364.123 | Operating System: Android

Chrome for Android renders css background SVGs and img tag SVGs horribly when on a dense pixel display. I'm having issues both on my GS3 and my Nexus 7.

Why does it output the SVGs like raster images? I've tried saving the SVGs as 4x larger, putting the width and height attributes on the imgs and then changing the size with CSS, still with no luck.

I know I could put the SVG inline, but inline SVGs completely break a site in IE8 or below. And I refuse to use multiple media queries and different size pngs to make up for this bug.

I've attached some screenshots, one from Chrome and one from the native default Browser. The default Browser seems to handle background SVGs decently, compared to Chrome. On the other hand, I also attached a Firefox screenshot; why can Gecko handle this but Webkit on Android Can't? And I'm not saying Webkit is to blame, because Chrome on my iPad 3 handles everything. Take a look at the screen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/h5SJP/

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457707/blurry-svg-images-in-chrome-for-android

Comment: Fixed by GC team http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=161982

Comment: thank you eugene I will check it out.