# SVG Background Image on Android Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, svg

I'm attempting to use an SVG as a background image and it looks fine in most browsers but, on Chrome (for Android - my version is 4.1.2) it's pixelated.  I've seen mentions of "fuzzy" SVG's in Chrome for Android but this appears to be different.  I tried [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457707/blurry-svg-images-in-chrome-for-android/16076247#16076247) and it did not help.  Any info / help would be greatly appreciated.

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/Batfan/Fec96/

```
#border {
width: 100%;
height: 15px;
background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9386314/triangle.svg) repeat-x center top;
background-size: 25px 15px;
}
```

.

Below is what I'm seeing on my phone:
[image]